# How to dynamically render react-i18next translations that access the translations from data contained in state?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have data in my state like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title1",
    "detail": {
      "en": "english detail1",
      "es": "catalan1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title2",
    "detail": {
      "en": "english detail2",
      "es": "catalan2"
    }
  }
]
```

I want react-i18next use the translation data from my state.
When I try using `<p>{t(`${el.detail}`)}</p>`, it returns `[object Object]`.
So, my question is how can I make react-i18next dynamically access translation data from my state or any other data, rather than from the i18n.js file?

Comment: It returns [object object] because detail contains two keys: "en" and "es". You have to specify which language key you want to access like this => <p>{t(${el.detail.en})}</p> to make it work. Is this you're asking Or I have understood it wrong ?

Comment: Yea, I know that. What I expected is that react-i18next can automatically use the translation from the "detail" key that matches the chosen language without defining them in the i18n.js file. My question is how can I achieve that.

Comment: As far as I know, i18 don't support this in a direct way, but you can achieve this way: Create one state which will keep track of current Locale and update that state value when Locale got changes. You can put this state into context or redux store according to your structure and that you can access in a Component this way - <p>{el.detail[language]}</p>. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the state data should be assigned to a variable in translation local file like

```
{
"el": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title1",
    "detail": {
      "en": "english detail1",
      "es": "catalan1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title2",
    "detail": {
      "en": "english detail2",
      "es": "catalan2"
    }
  }
]
}
```

you can get the data in your component using usetranslation like

```
const {t} = useTranslation();
const details = t("el", {returnObjects: true});
```

ready now you can use the "details" data how ever you like and it worked fine for me